# CodeIgniter: Get data where current time is in between tbl_from_time and tbl_to_time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, backend

```
**NOTE:** $cur_time = Current Time
```

I want to select the current schedule of a professor based on the current time   by selecting the data where `tbl_from_time >= $cur_time <= tbl_to_time`.

i.e.
DATABASE TABLE: 'schedule'

```
| sched_id | weekday | from_time | to_time  | room       | prof_id | date_created        |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+---------+---------------------+
|        7 |       1 | 07:30:00  | 09:00:00 | SR12       |       1 | 2017-05-14 11:16:54 |
|        2 |       1 | 12:00:00  | 13:30:00 | ORC 12     |       1 | 2017-05-14 11:21:47 |
|        3 |       1 | 10:30:00  | 12:00:00 | Comp Lab 6 |       1 | 2017-05-14 11:22:20 |
|        4 |       1 | 09:00:00  | 10:30:00 | Comp Lab 4 |       1 | 2017-05-14 13:00:57 |
|        8 |       1 | 07:30:00  | 08:32:00 | Comp Lab 3 |       1 | 2017-05-15 14:42:28 |
|        9 |       1 | 06:45:00  | 07:45:00 | Comp Lab 3 |       1 | 2017-05-15 14:45:45 |
|       10 |       1 | 18:00:00  | 19:07:00 | Comp Lab 3 |       1 | 2017-05-15 18:07:48 |
|       11 |       2 | 12:02:00  | 01:56:00 | Sample     |       1 | 2017-05-16 10:17:45 |
```

MY QUERY

```
function get_current_schedule($prof_id, $cur_time, $weekday) {
        $this->db->select()->from('schedule');
        $this->db->where('prof_id', $prof_id);
        $this->db->where('weekday', $weekday);
        $where = "'$cur_time' BETWEEN from_time and to_time";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->first_row();    
    }
```

Comment: what is your data stored format for 'tbl_from_time' and 'tbl_to_time'?
please make your dummy table here with 2-3 records and your query efforts also.

Comment: @Nidhi I updated the question above.

Comment: Try this in MySQL: SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE  '09:58:00' BETWEEN from_time AND to_time AND prof_id='1' AND weekday='2'.

Comment: It worked by I changed the weekday = 1, cause there will be no result. Thank you much

Comment: Hope you got your error and go ahead in the work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to get data between form and to.

```
function get_current_schedule($prof_id, $cur_time, $weekday) {
      $result =  $this->db->select()
        ->from('schedule')
        ->where('prof_id', $prof_id)
        ->where('weekday', $weekday)
        ->where('from_time >=', $cur_time)
        ->where('tbl_to_time <=', $cur_time)        
        ->get();

        return $result->first_row();    
    }
```